# Google analytics adds results of a non existing page

Tags: google-analytics

I'm really new to this so bear with me please.

I've added Google analytic to my very small and basic website recently and it's showing me results to a non-existing page in a non-existing location!

here's the page:

```
/data/5245/51df5d5ef235afefd5a583439a9de3315fdf0b70.html
```

anybody knows why, what or is this normal?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a static website or a Content Management System like wordpress, joomla or typo3? If you use a CMS, maybe this software is creating this temporary file.

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the page?

Comment: Check the hostname, it could be that your site was scraped.